# How to specify which group each columns should belong in pandas explicitly?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have dataframe with following columns.

> [A,B,C,D,E,F,G...]

I want to use groupby method for this dataframe specifying which group each column should belong to as below.

> group1=[A,C,D,G...]
>   group2=[B,E,F...]

I could find some page explaining how to use groupby with condition. But could not find answer which fit to this question.
Could anyone tell me how to implement this logic?

Comment: Can you add example of dataframe and desired output after groupby?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe need:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'F':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'G':[4,5,4,5,5,4]})

print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G
0  4  4  7  1  5  4  4
1  5  5  8  3  3  5  5
2  4  4  9  5  6  4  4
3  5  5  4  7  9  5  5
4  5  5  2  1  2  5  5
5  4  4  3  0  4  4  4
```

Create dictionary of groups in `list`s and then swap keys with values in dicts comprehension with flattening:

```
d = {'g1':['A','C','D','G'], 'g2':['B','E','F']}
d1 = {k: oldk for oldk, oldv in d.items() for k in oldv}
print (d1) 
{'A': 'g1', 'C': 'g1', 'D': 'g1', 'G': 'g1', 'B': 'g2', 'E': 'g2', 'F': 'g2'}

df = df.groupby(d1, axis=1).sum()
print (df) 
   g1  g2
0  16  13
1  21  13
2  22  14
3  21  19
4  13  12
5  11  12
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a dictionary that defines the groupings then use that dictionary in a `groupby` on `axis=1`

```
m = {
    *dict.from_keys(['A', 'C', 'D', 'G'], 'group1'),
    *dict.from_keys(['B', 'E', 'F'], 'group2'),
}

df.groupby(m, axis=1).mean()
```

Answer (score 2):

By using for loop with `concat`

```
l=[['A', 'C', 'D', 'G'],['B', 'E', 'F']]
pd.concat([df[x].sum(1) for x in l],1)
Out[322]: 
    0   1
0  16  13
1  21  13
2  22  14
3  21  19
4  13  12
5  11  12
```